# Rewriting URLs with mod_rewrite 

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm currently rewriting urls from

```
http://domain.com/profile/?u=10000017564881
```

this to this

```
http://domain.com/profile/10000017564881
```

with the following rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/?$ index.php?u=$1 [L]
```

However I'd like to optimize for seo a litte and go with :

```
http://domain.com/profile/10000017564881/Anything-I-want-here
```

Obviously the /Anything-I-want-here is just null ignored ...

Any idea's guys?
much appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply remove the `$` from the regex, and anything after the ID number will be ignored, and the URL will be rewritten correctly.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/? index.php?u=$1 [L]

# the following will work the same (as far as I can tell), and
# it's a lot more obvious at first glance what it does, which is
# match everything until the first slash
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)     ...
```

When I do something like this, I like to verify the URL in code, and 301 redirect if the "Anything-I-want-here" doesn't match the data.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([^/])\/? index.php?u=$1 [L]   

Like this? doesn't seem to work buddy Did I write it correctly?

Comment: You're right, I forgot a `+`. I tested the updated one at http://regexpal.com/ and it works fine. You can omit the `\/?` and it will still work.